# Does Windows 11 Pro work simultaneously with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in dual boot by installing with Wubiuefi?

Tags: dual-boot

My computer is not so new. And I'm afraid that the resource is not enough. If I select to boot Ubuntu, will only Ubuntu work after booting ?

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, then you will only run one OS at a time; either Windows or Ubuntu. If you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), then you are using a virtualised version of Ubuntu within Windows.

Comment: Dear @matigo, Thank you so much and your comment is the answer to my uncleared question. I need to install alongside Windows.

Comment: I have done that on several systems for many years. I no longer do it, I just install Ubuntu, windows offers nothing I want that is not on Ubuntu. It is also handy in that you can access windows files and fix a broken windows if you know how but not the other way around.